# What is the best free method of approximating Windows 7 power management in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, power-management

I previously had Windows XP Tablet Ed. on my HP TC4400. Now I have Windows 7 installed on it and I've noticed quite a substantial increase in battery life, in particular when using the power saver profile.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how best to approximate the power management features present in Windows 7 that are not present in Windows XP? For example Windows 7 allows one to set a ceiling for processor speed - this is not option is not available in Windows XP (at least not from the power management dialog box); Windows 7 offers similar power saving t. What free, hopefully easy to use, 3rd party software offer good ways of extending XP's power management capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend [Notebook Hardware Control](http://www.pbus-167.com/) again. It worked pretty good for me while I was using windows on my laptop.

Comment: A note about NHC, the development has been "on hold" for a while, but it seems that the author is back on it (according to the forum, I think), and a new version should come some day.